# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 415

Tags: php, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

[image]

**my code **

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $type = $_POST["type"];
        $content  = $_POST["content"];
         $description = $_POST['description'];
         $postdata = 
            array(
                'title' => $title,
                'type' => $type,
                'content' => $content,
                'description' => $description,
                
            );
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($postdata),
            )
        );
        
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        
        $result = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/project_war_exploded/admin/blog', false, $context);
        echo $result;

}




?>
```

I am getting error

> file_get_contents(http://localhost:8080/project_war_exploded/admin/blog):
> Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 415"**

what is the reason, can anyone help me ?

Like I said - call from the postman and it works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

415 means `Unsupported media type`. You send `www-form-urlencoded` what is not expected by the backend.
Add the correct content type to the header, like `application/json` in this example

```
   $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
            'content' => http_build_query($postdata),
        )
    );
```